# Bootstrap carousel buttons not aligning veritcally on smaller screens

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using **Twitter Bootstrap 3.1.1**.

Source code: http://jsfiddle.net/iglvzx/7g7dy/

I am adding a [carousel](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel) to the top of my website and I have chosen to not use the indicator dots on each slide. (I omitted the `<ol class="carousel-indicators">` element)

The problem that I am running into is that the next and previous buttons are not centered vertically on smaller screens.

Here's how it looks at full size: [image: screenshot, 1280x]

And here's how it looks when the screen size is smaller: [image: screenshot, 320x]

How can I get the next and previous buttons/icons to align vertically on smaller screens? The buttons are moving further south the smaller the screen gets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add following code to your css file and change `font-size`, `line-height` and `margin-top` as you want. Just make `font-size` and `line-height` equal and `margin-top` must be half their size.

http://jsfiddle.net/7g7dy/2/

```
.carousel-control .icon-prev, .carousel-control .icon-next, .carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-left, .carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-right {
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 24px;
  margin-top: -12px;
}
```

Comment: Why change the font size/line-height?

Comment: `font-size` is optional. If we make `line-height` equal as `font-size` we can make icons' size vertically correct. This way we can calculate exact size we need for negative margin.

Answer (score 1):

This also happens on http://getbootstrap.com. It appears they set `top: 50%` but not a negative margin equal to half the chevron's height (as they do on desktop).

You'd be better served filing this as an issue on Bootstrap's GitHub page: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues

If you need a workaround now, I would write a rule for `.carousel-control .glyphicon` and give it a margin-top of -1/2(x) where x is the height of the chevron. This should be about 8px on mobile.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .carousel-control .glyphicon { margin-top: -8px; }
}
```